# Why is my sentence incorrect?

Tags: indirect-speech

My  solution: Jake told me yesterday that he **was going** to the party at Helen’s house the week before.

The teacher's solution: Jake told me yesterday that he **had gone** to the party at Helen’s house the week before.

Can somebody explain me, why? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think your sentence is correct? Please explain.

Comment: The wording "was going" in your version of the sentence would mean that Jake's going was either at the same time as his telling you or at a later time. It contradicts "the week before".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Had gone** is the past perfect conjugation of the verb "to go". The past perfect tense is

> a tense which represents actions that occurred before other actions in the past

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/past_perfect

The action that occurred in the past was Jake telling you something, but the action before that was Jake going to the party at Helen’s house the week before. Therefore, the past perfect **had gone** is correct.

Comment: The teacher said in indirect speech Past Continous doesn't become Past Perfect (usually). I think she may not have right.

So, was going to --> had gone is true in all case?

Comment: To let people answer your question (or judge if your teacher is right or wrong) you should start with posting the **exact question**, and only then the answers. ;-)